# Trim spaces in a object recursively using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, system.reflection

I am writing an extension method TrimSpaces on a object so that it recursively should be able to trim spaces. I was successful in trimming the spaces for the first level object, however, I am unable to do the same for the child objects.

As an example, consider the following class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public Department EmployeeDepartment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class I am currently able to trim spaces from Employee class properties but I am unable to trim the DepartmentName

Here is the code that I have written

```
    public static T TrimSpaces<T>(this T obj)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (value.HasValue())
            {
                var newValue = (object)value.Trim();
                property.SetValue(obj, newValue, null);
            }
        }


        var customTypes =
            obj.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(
                    prop =>
                        !prop.GetType().IsPrimitive && prop.GetType().IsClass &&
                        !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System"));

        foreach (var customType in customTypes)
        {
            ((object)customType.GetValue(obj).GetType()).TrimSpaces();
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `((object)customType.GetValue(obj)).TrimSpaces();`, i.e., without `.GetType()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you loop through the properties, you are invoking this line:

```
((object)customType.GetValue(obj).GetType()).TrimSpaces();
```

Which invokes `TrimSpaces` passing the type of the object as `obj`. Instead you should pass the object it self like this:

```
((object)customType.GetValue(obj)).TrimSpaces();
```

In which case, the cast to `object` is not needed, so you can have this:

```
customType.GetValue(obj).TrimSpaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

> As Yacoub pointed out, I have used GetValue and then called
>   TrimSpaces. Just like the last time I have tried to do it that way, I
>   got a null reference exception. I have written a null check at the
>   starting of the method to avoid the same. Also, for reasons that I
>   don't know yet, I was getting a "TargetParameterCountException". For
>   that I have added a check to the customType I was searching for should
>   not be a primitive type. With those changes the code seems to work.
>
> As a side note, the object on which I was planning to do trimming is
>   complex deep nesting object with various user defined classes as
>   properties with at least 5 level deep nesting. I am still yet to
>   figure out on why null reference exception is occurring and also the
>   TargetParameterCountException
>
> Below is the final code that I am using which is doing the job.I would
>   update this answer if I have any bug fixes

Ok. I have figured out what was the issue and below is the code with comments updated. I am also leaving the old code so that anyone checking this question in future will know the context

```
 public static T TrimSpaces<T>(this T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return obj;
        }

        //Iterates all properties and trims the values if they are strings
        var properties = obj.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (value.HasValue())
            {
                var newValue = (object)value.Trim();
                property.SetValue(obj, newValue, null);
            }
        }


        // This is to take care of Lists. This iterates through each value
        // in the list.
        // For example, Countries which is a List<Country>
        var baseTypeInfo = obj.GetType().BaseType;
        if (baseTypeInfo != null && baseTypeInfo.FullName.Contains("List"))
        {
            int listCount = (int)obj.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(obj, null);
            for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < listCount; innerIndex++)
            {
                object item = obj.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("get_Item", new Type[] { typeof(int) })
                    .Invoke(obj, new object[] { innerIndex });
                item.TrimSpaces();
            }
        }


        // Now once we are in a complex type (for example Country) it then needs to
        // be trimmed recursively using the initial peice of code of this method
        // Hence if it is a complex type we are recursively calling TrimSpaces
        var customTypes =
            obj.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(
                    prop =>
                        !prop.GetType().IsPrimitive && prop.GetType().IsClass &&
                        !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System"));

        foreach (var customType in customTypes)
        {
            // If it's a collection, let the about piece of code take care
            // Only, normal types like, Code etc will be trimmed
            if (customType.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                customType.GetValue(obj).TrimSpaces();
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Old Code:

> ```
> public static T TrimSpaces<T>(this T obj)
>     {
>
>         if (obj == null)
>         {
>             return obj;
>         }
>
>         var properties = obj.GetType()
>             .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
>             .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
>             .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);
>         foreach (var property in properties)
>         {
>             var value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null);
>             if (value.HasValue())
>             {
>                 var newValue = (object)value.Trim();
>                 property.SetValue(obj, newValue, null);
>             }
>         }
>
>
>         var customTypes =
>             obj.GetType()
>                 .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
>                 .Where(
>                     prop =>
>                         !prop.GetType().IsPrimitive && prop.GetType().IsClass &&
>                         !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System"));
>
>         foreach (var customType in customTypes)
>         {
>             if (customType.Name.Contains("Item"))
>             {
>                 continue;
>             }
>
>             customType.GetValue(obj).TrimSpaces();
>         }
>
>         return obj;
>     }
> ```