# To trim an string before model validation occurs in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a DTO class that is bound from body source to create my user:

```
    public class UserDto
    {
        [Required()]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [SocialSerialNumber]
        public string SSN { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [PhoneNumber]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public bool? Gender { get; set; }  
        [Required]
        [MinLength(6)]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        [IgnoreTrim]  // this is what I need
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to trim (remove extra spaces from) all my strings in all of my models before validation. Trimming must be ignored for strings I explicitly specified as no-trim (maybe using an attribute called `[IgnoreTrim]`).

In the example above trimming for properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber` is needed but not `Password`.

I know that I can manually trim them in the controller action and then revalidate the model, But I'm looking for graceful way of doing this so that my action stays clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Found a nice solution using **custom model binder** and **custom JSON converter**.

```
public class StringTrimmerBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(bindingContext);

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value.Trim());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

StringTrimmerBinder is my custom binder that transforms the string to a trimmed string using `Trim()` method. To use this binder I made a custom `IModelBinderProvider` that is is used to to resolve a binder for specified type (in my case string type).

```
public class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));


        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string) && context.BindingInfo.BindingSource!=BindingSource.Body)
            return new StringTrimmerBinder();

        return null;
    }
}
```

So I register `CustomModelBinderProvider` like this:

```
services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    //registers CustomModelBinderProvider in the first place so that it is asked before other model binder providers.
    opt.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider());
});
```

Until now everything is ok and all string models are trimmed except those which their binding source is request body ([FromBody]). Because default model binders uses `System.Text.Json` namespace to convert request body to model types, instead of making a new binder that to the same job, I create a JSON converter that customize converting body to model types.

Here is my custom converter:

```
public class StringTrimmerJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString()?.Trim();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

And here is the way to use this converter:

```
services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    opt.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider());
})
    .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new StringTrimmerJsonConverter());
    });
```

That's it, now all my strings whether in *complex-type* or in *simple-type* will be trimmed.

Comment: of course now you we can make a `[NoTrim]` attribute that ignores trimming the string. this is what I've done in my project but not included in this response

Comment: What problem do you get if you don't include `&& context.BindingInfo.BindingSource!=BindingSource.Body`?

Comment: `StringTrimmerBinder` seems to somehow convert `null` to `string.Empty`.

Comment: I fixed the code to honor `null`.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

I have included two model binders that work with JSON and Form fields data from the body.

Implement `IModelBinder` and do the following:

Bind from Json:

```
public class CustomModelBinderJson : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string body;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        var dataModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataModel>(body);

        dataModel.Name = dataModel.Name.Trim();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dataModel);
    }
}
```

Or bind from form fields:

```
public class CustomModelBinderForm : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var form = request.Form["Name"];
        var id = request.Form["Id"];
        var dataModel = new DataModel();

        dataModel.Id = int.Parse(id);
        dataModel.Name = form.ToString().Trim();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dataModel);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then

```
 [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinderForm))] //Or use the CustomModelBinderJson
    public class DataModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Your action should look someting like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromBody] DataModel dataModel)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

See [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I think model binder is not suitable when my model is bound from body

Comment: @MohammadBarbast It is suitable, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But your solution is just for an specified type, In my case I want to trim all my strings in all of my models except those I explicitly specified ( maybe using attributes or anything)

Comment: I updated the question, may you take a look

Answer (score 1):

You may use the getter to trim the value that's going to be stored in a private field. In this way, your validation will be against the trimmed value

For example with the property `FirstName`

```cs
public class UserDto
{
    private string firstName;

    [Required()]
    [PersianChars]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return firstName?.Trim(); 
        }
        set 
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is implementing a custom attribute that indicates which properties need to be trimmed before validation. At this point you can automate this process

---

To automate the process of trimming the values of the properties using a custom attribute:

You need to create a **Custom Attribute**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TrimmedValueAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then, add the attribute to the desidered properties, for example `FirstName`

```cs
public class UserDto
{
    [Required()]
    [PersianChars]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [TrimmedValue]
    public string FirstName { get; set }
}
```

After that, you need to create an **Action Filter** which automatically trims the properties that has the `TrimmedValueAttribute`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-filters

```cs
public class TrimPropertiesActionFilter : IActionFilter 
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        Use reflection to find all the properties which has the TrimValueAttribute 
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, add the filter on your `ConfigureServices` method

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(TrimPropertiesActionFilter));
    });
}
```

You can change the order of the action filters by settings the second argument of the `Add` method

```cs
options.Filters.Add(typeof(TrimPropertiesActionFilter, order: 0));
```

Comment: I really need to know how this can be done with a custom attribute, May you give me some clues how to implement it?

Comment: That's nice idea But model validation takes place before action filters. So trimming occurs after model validation

Comment: have you tried to specify the order of the action filter? using the second argument
like `options.Filters.Add(typeof(TrimPropertiesActionFilter, 0));`

Comment: I was wrong about the time web API automatic model validation occurs, I should check your advice. thanks

Comment: Is it possible to change action models in action filters? I didn't manage to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom middleware and with a reflection find the `string` properties and trim them.

In case you want to trim specific string properties, you may implement a custom interface that includes the properties you wish to trim, and then in the custom middleware run over all the properties of the custom interface and trim them.

You can see an example of custom middleware [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-E6TbePgH1SRQ1GfL.xRgeQ&epi=a1LgFw09t88-E6TbePgH1SRQ1GfL.xRgeQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xri0qn6vo1uqu00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-E6TbePgH1SRQ1GfL.xRgeQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xri0qn6vo1uqu00).

And also see how to trim a string with a reflection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234810/trim-spaces-in-a-object-recursively-using-reflection).

And another approach would be to build a [custom model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation) to manipulate the data.